# Sqlite3 could not execute prepared statement with error "unable to open database file"

Tags: sqlite

I have a long running process that has inserted tens of thousands of records into a sqlite3 database running in wal mode on ubuntu linux 4.4.0.

Randomly about 10 of it's transactions failed because sqlite3 was "unable to open database file".

All of those failures were simple updates to the same table.

Before these failures many transactions were successfully committed to the database by the same process.

Several of those transactions were inserts to the table with the problem, and others were inserts and updates to other tables.

While the process was still running the problem fixed itself and updates to the table simply started working.

None of the transactions use temporary tables, or have group bys. They are all simple selects, inserts or updates.

There were no other non root or system level processes running on the host that might have somehow messed up the permissions.

The sqlite3 process has permission to write to /tmp and /var/tmp and successfully writes to /var/tmp.

The process never sets sqlite's locking mode.

There is nothing funny about the database path, it is just ascii.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're not changing the `locking_mode` before attaching the database?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thank you for the suggestion. the process never sets the locking mode

Comment: If the locking mode hasn't been changed it should afaik be more or less painless to do what you're doing, so sadly I can't really think of any other reason off hand.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that you're leaking connections and are running out of file handles.

Comment: @CL. Thanks you for suggesting that. I am pretty sure that is not the case. the application is single threaded and normally runs tens of thousands more transactions than this in its process lifetime without seeing this issue. But i will double check. Unfortunately i cant reproduce this problem